# BFS and DFS implementations - Suggestions and improvements

Tags: python, optimization, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I would like you to check out the implementations of Breadth First Search and Depth First Search in the [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Bwu94JjPzgmXWPw8Znr--OfD4GQTH-1P?usp=sharing).

Is this the right way to go? Can I make any improvements? Any misc suggestions would also be appreciated.

I was trying to implement Breadth First Search and Depth First Search. I would like to optimize it.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate D.L's comment, your question needs to have a desired outcome, and a code/design to which we can assess against that desired outcome. So, I'm only giving an opinion and not an answer.

Your code seems fine. I think you did all that basic BFS and DFS algorithms should do.
You could go into the theoretical direction for optimizations. Time and Space Complexity, and maybe ways to decrease resource usage.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-is-the-complexity-of-both-bfs-and-dfs-ove/

After understanding that, you could learn the "upgraded" versions - Dijkstra's, A*, Bidirectional Search, Search using sortings - with different queue and stack variations like MinPQ, MaxPQ. I'm sure you've heard of them.

On the other hand, if you're interested in getting evaluated quickly, just do leetcode questions and review their forums.

- https://leetcode.com/tag/breadth-first-search/
- https://leetcode.com/tag/depth-first-search/
- https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-time-to-collect-all-apples-in-a-tree/solutions/732001/DFS-to-traverse-Graph/

Happy Learning!